# identify customers with at least one purchase per month and assign to category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with sales data and it looks like this

```
customer_id date    store_location  amount_paid year    month
442608921   2021-01-01  Austin  11968   2021    1
865639331   2021-01-01  San Antonio 41970   2021    1
442643778   2021-01-01  Denver  900 2021    1
442643777   2021-01-01  Denver  2258    2021    1
442643774   2021-01-01  Boston  866 2021    1
442643775   2021-01-01  Los Angeles 866 2021    1
442643776   2021-01-01  Austin  1194    2021    1
601469342   2021-01-01  Austin  5163    2021    1
333570465   2021-01-01  Denver  8000    2021    1
```

The data is for the period 1 Jan 2021 to 30 April 2022

I want to identify customers who have made at least one purchase per month during that period and create a new column with the values 1 for customers with at least one purchase per month, and 0 for less active or inactive customers. How can I do this with python?

I tried this and it gives me the number of purchases per year and month, but I haven’t figure out how to assign the values 0 and 1.

```
grpd=df.groupby(['customer_id','year','month']).size().to_frame('n_purchases').reset_index().sort_values(['customer_id, 'year', 'month'], ascending=[True, True, True])
grpd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
def foo(x):
    y = {(x.year[i], x.month[i]) for i in x.index}
    year, month = 2021, 1
    for i in range(16):
        if (year, month) not in y:
            return False
        month = month % 12 + 1
        year = year + (1 if month == 1 else 0)
    return True
    
df2 = df.groupby('customer_id').apply(foo).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'frequent_customer'})
df = df.join(df2, on='customer_id')
```

Explanation:

- group by `customer_id` and use apply to check for each group whether each `year, month` tuple from 2021-01 to 2022-04 can be found in the set of unique `year, month` purchase rows for that group
- name that boolean column `frequent_customer` in a new dataframe with one row per `customer_id`
- use `join` to add a `frequent_customer` column to the original dataframe

---

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'customer_id': [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5],
'date':[
    '2021-01-01',
    '2021-01-01',
    '2021-01-01',
    '2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2021-04-01','2021-05-01','2021-06-01','2021-07-01','2021-08-01','2021-09-01','2021-10-01','2021-11-01','2021-12-01','2022-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-01',
    '2021-01-01'],
'store_location':['Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin','Austin'],
'amount_paid':[900]*20
})
df[['year','month']] = pd.DataFrame(df.date.str.split('-').str.slice(0, 2).tolist(), index = df.index).astype(int)
print(df)

def foo(x):
    y = {(x.year[i], x.month[i]) for i in x.index}
    year, month = 2021, 1
    for i in range(16):
        if (year, month) not in y:
            return False
        month = month % 12 + 1
        year = year + (1 if month == 1 else 0)
    return True
    
df2 = df.groupby('customer_id').apply(foo).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'frequent_customer'})
df = df.join(df2, on='customer_id')
print(df)
```

Input:

```
    customer_id        date store_location  amount_paid  year  month
0             1  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1
1             2  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1
2             3  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1
3             4  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1
4             4  2021-02-01         Austin          900  2021      2
5             4  2021-03-01         Austin          900  2021      3
6             4  2021-04-01         Austin          900  2021      4
7             4  2021-05-01         Austin          900  2021      5
8             4  2021-06-01         Austin          900  2021      6
9             4  2021-07-01         Austin          900  2021      7
10            4  2021-08-01         Austin          900  2021      8
11            4  2021-09-01         Austin          900  2021      9
12            4  2021-10-01         Austin          900  2021     10
13            4  2021-11-01         Austin          900  2021     11
14            4  2021-12-01         Austin          900  2021     12
15            4  2022-01-01         Austin          900  2022      1
16            4  2022-02-01         Austin          900  2022      2
17            4  2022-03-01         Austin          900  2022      3
18            4  2022-04-01         Austin          900  2022      4
19            5  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1
```

Output:

```
    customer_id        date store_location  amount_paid  year  month  frequent_customer
0             1  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1              False
1             2  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1              False
2             3  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1              False
3             4  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1               True
4             4  2021-02-01         Austin          900  2021      2               True
5             4  2021-03-01         Austin          900  2021      3               True
6             4  2021-04-01         Austin          900  2021      4               True
7             4  2021-05-01         Austin          900  2021      5               True
8             4  2021-06-01         Austin          900  2021      6               True
9             4  2021-07-01         Austin          900  2021      7               True
10            4  2021-08-01         Austin          900  2021      8               True
11            4  2021-09-01         Austin          900  2021      9               True
12            4  2021-10-01         Austin          900  2021     10               True
13            4  2021-11-01         Austin          900  2021     11               True
14            4  2021-12-01         Austin          900  2021     12               True
15            4  2022-01-01         Austin          900  2022      1               True
16            4  2022-02-01         Austin          900  2022      2               True
17            4  2022-03-01         Austin          900  2022      3               True
18            4  2022-04-01         Austin          900  2022      4               True
19            5  2021-01-01         Austin          900  2021      1              False
```

Comment: Thanks @constantstranger. I'd like to learn more about the construction of those functions. Where can I look?. Cheers

Comment: This part of the pandas docs explains [String Methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-string-methods) such as `split` and `slice`. It's a good place to start.